# React webpack. Не работает приложение без .tsx в компоненте

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

Коллеги, привет.
Приложение не грузится, пока я не допишу расширение .tsx в компоненте. В extensions webpack прописаны все необходимые расширения. Если в компоненте допишу App.tsx, то все работает. Не пойму в чем проблема, ведь должно работать и без приписки .tsx?
[image: App.tsx]

[image: error]

[image: webpack config]